# Big realm compacted file size

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have realm file with size about 700mb. I create compacted version using `realm.writeToCopyURL()`, but I get file with the same 700mb. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(im)writeCopyToURL:encryptionKey:error:) is never mentioned that that method should compress your file, you only get an encrypted version.

If you want to compress your Realm, you'll have to do it before encrypting it.

Comment: Ok, new question. How to compress it?

Comment: New question should be a new question on Stack Overflow.